# JLabel doesn't change when setBackground() and setBorder() are called

Tags: java, jlabel

I've been working on a snake program for one of my classes. It runs perfectly except for one small problem: In `View` (extends `JLabel`) I set the background to `Color.WHITE`, `opaque` to `true` and the border to `Color.GREEN` in the constructor. None of these lines seem to affect the GUI.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class View extends JLabel {
    private Snake snake;
    private Fruit fruit;
    private Game game;

    public View(int size, Game g) {
        int W = Game.SIZE * Snake.SIZE;
        int H = Game.SIZE * Snake.SIZE;
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBounds((Game.WIDTH-W)/2, (Game.HEIGHT-H)/2, W, H);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
        snake = new Snake(Snake.SIZE, Snake.SIZE);
        fruit = new Fruit();
        game = g;

    }

    public void start() {
        boolean flag = true;
        snake.start();

        while(flag) {
            snake.move();
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void move(int dir) {
        snake.move(dir);
    }

    public void doDrawing(Graphics2D g) {
        int s = snake.SIZE;
        int fx = fruit.getX();
        int fy = fruit.getY();
        g.setColor(Game.SNAKE_COLOR);
        Snake sn = snake;
        boolean flag = true;
        while(flag) {
            g.fillRect(sn.getX(), sn.getY(), s, s);
            if(sn.hasTail()) {
                sn = sn.getTail();
            }
            else flag = false;
        }

        g.setColor(Game.FRUIT_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(fx, fy, s, s);

        if(snake.getX() == fx && snake.getY() == fy) {
            snake.ate();
            fruit.create();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        game.repaint();
        Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D) g;
        doDrawing(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are overriding the `paint` method, yet never calling `super.paint()` to let the parent class perform its painting operation. [More information available here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Some other suggestions for improvement:

1. Instead of using `paint()`, you should be overriding `paintComponent()` and in one of the first lines of the method make a call to the parent painting routine `super.paintComponent(g)`.
2. You might consider extending `JPanel` or `JComponent` rather than `JLabel`, as you seem to not use any functionality of this class.
3. Do NOT call repaint in your painting method

Comment: Thank you! super.paint(g) fixed it

Comment: 1+ @kemp5, No.... that is NOT the solution. You should be overriding paintComponent(). You should NOT be extending JLabel. I also doubt that you should be invoking game.repaint(). A painting method should never invoke repaint() on another component. Don't take the easy way out. Listen to all the suggestions!!!

Comment: Okay I changed paint() to paintComponent() and change View to extend JComponent rather than JLabel. The only thing is if I remove game.repaint() The "snake" continues to draw where ever it goes since the starting point.

Answer (score -1):

```
package snake;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class View extends JComponent {
    private Snake snake;
    private Fruit fruit;
    private Game game;

    public View(int size, Game g) {
        int W = Control.SIZE * Snake.SIZE;
        int H = Control.SIZE * Snake.SIZE;
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds((Game.WIDTH-W)/2, (Game.HEIGHT-H)/2, W, H);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
        snake = new Snake(Snake.SIZE, Snake.SIZE);
        fruit = new Fruit();
        game = g;

    }

    public void start() {
        boolean flag = true;
        snake.start();

        while(flag) {
            snake.move();
            repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(Control.TIME);
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void move(int dir) {
        snake.move(dir);
    }

    public void doDrawing(Graphics2D g) {
        int s = Snake.SIZE;
        int fx = fruit.getX();
        int fy = fruit.getY();
        g.setColor(Control.SNAKE_COLOR);

        snake.display(g);

        g.setColor(Control.FRUIT_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(fx, fy, s, s);

        if(snake.getX() == fx && snake.getY() == fy) {
            snake.ate();
            fruit.create();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        game.repaint();

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D d = (Graphics2D) g;
        doDrawing(d);
    }
}
```

Game extends JFrame